# ¿Cuándo se adaptó la canción del "cumpleaños feliz" al español?

Tags: historia, letras-de-canciones

Una pregunta rápida por pura curiosidad desde el móvil y aprovechando que hoy es mi cumpleaños: se tiene constancia de que la canción del "cumpleaños feliz" se originó como un canto para saludar a los niños de una guardería:

> Good morning to all,
>   good morning to all,
>   good morning dear children,
>   good morning to all.

Esta canción se atribuye a las hermanas Patty y Mildred Hill como compuesta en 1893. Su melodía se incorporó a la letra del "Happy birthday to you" que es como la conocemos hoy, y supongo que de ahí saltó al español.

¿Se sabe cuál fue la primera versión de dicha canción en español? ¿Quién la adaptó? ¿En qué año fue?

Comment: Feliz cumpleaños!!

Comment: Japi verdi tuyu

Comment: En Argentina la letra es "Que los cumplas feliz..."

Answer (score 4):

Lo primero: ¡feliz cumpleaños!

Según [la base de datos de la United States Copyright Office](http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?v1=3&ti=1,3&Search_Arg=Cumplea%C3%B1os%20feliz&Search_Code=TALL&CNT=25&PID=Y78dnaGdbk34mBBAJKRvxwc4iOn&SEQ=20170530180843&SID=1), la primera adaptación registrada en USA de la canción al idioma español data de 1961.

En el [buscador de la SGAE](https://socios.sgae.es/RepertorioOnline/Buscar.aspx?opcion=buscar), buscando por "cumpleaños feliz" aparece la misma obra con el mismo autor registrada con nº 7.480, pero no viene el año de registro. Sin embargo, buscando otras canciones de la epoca con fecha de composicion conocida, me encuentro que el tema [*Peggy Sue*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peggy_Sue), compuesto en 1957, está registrado en la SGAE con nº 7.761.
**Esto situaría el registro de la canción en España en el año 1957**.

Los nombres del copyright son: Julia Hernández Tudón, y José de Juan del Águila (presidente de Unión Musical Española por aquel entonces).
Esto no quiere decir que la adaptación sea original suya. Al menos en el caso de José de Juan del Águila, existen docenas de canciones populares españolas, como *Los peces en el río* o *Uno de enero, dos de febrero*, que están registradas a su nombre o bajo alguno de sus seudónimos (siendo los más conocidos: J. Trayter, y m.J. Cortina). Esto lo pudo hacer por el simple hecho de que nadie las había registrado antes, aun cuando el autor de algunas de ellas era ya conocido.
Para el caso de "Cumpleaños feliz" no sabemos si la letra ya era popular por aquel entonces y este hombre se limitó a registrarla como propia, o si realmente fue una composición original.

Buscando en Google se puede encontrar bastante información sobre José de Juan del Águila. Sobre Julia Hernández Tudón, en cambio, lo único que sale es que murió en Barcelona en 2013 a los 95 años de edad. Quizá fuera otro seudónimo del señor Del Águila.